# Prove that for every $ \quad n\in\mathbb{N},\quad \mathbb{R}^{n} = \mathfrak{c}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

```
I was thinking about induction like:
```

Base:
$$\#\mathbb{R}^{1} = \#\mathbb{R} = \mathfrak{c}$$ 
 
And for $n+1$ 
 $$\#\mathbb{R}^{n+1} = \#\mathbb{R}^{n}\mathbb{R} = \mathfrak{c}$$ 
 But it seems too easy. Do you have some other ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you already know that $\Bbb{R\times R}$ and $\Bbb R$ have the same cardinality, then this is enough.

Comment: So many rep. points for this? :) +1 just for that :D

Comment: Meh, I've had much more for much less. :-)

Comment: Or "I have lost to better players than you!"

Comment: I'm debating with myself whether or not you also need to know that if $|B| = |C|$, then $|A \times B| = |A \times C|$. Almost too obvious to include, but perhaps there's something in it, since after all it's untrue if you replace $\times$ by $\cup$.

Comment: @Ben: That's an immediate consequence of the definition of cardinal multiplication: $$|A\times B|=|A|\cdot|B|=|A|\cdot|C|=|A\times C|.$$

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'd say it's a prerequisite of the definition of cardinal multiplication. You need to check it's true before that definition of cardinal multiplication makes sense.

Comment: @Ben: You're probably absolutely right, maybe. I've had a long and tiresome day... :-)